# How to evaluate the accuracy of a probability distribution?

Tags: accuracy, bayesian-network, density-estimation

I've trained a Gaussian Bayesian Network. If I feed input values for the parent variables of my output variable, I get a normal distribution. How can I quantify the accuracy of this distribution when confronted to the real data? Should I just use the variance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways of assessing the accuracy of predictive densities.

The simplest would be a [Probability Integral Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform): evaluate your predicted CDF at the observed outcome. If your predicted CDF is the correct density, then the result will be uniformly distributed on [0,1]. (This is just a different way of looking at the definition of the CDF.) This is rather simple to understand, but since your CDF being correct is a *sufficient* condition for the PIT to be uniform, not a *necessary* one, your predicted CDF may be wrong even if your PIT is uniform ([Gneiting et al., 2007](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2007.00587.x)).

A more correct, but less easily understood, approach is to use proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules). These are functions of your predicted density and the actual outcome that will be minimized in expectation by the correct density. See [Gneiting et al. (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2007.00587.x) and [Gneiting & Katzfuss (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-statistics-062713-085831). (Note that there are different conventions in the literature: Gneiting et al. use "negatively oriented" scoring rules, where smaller is better, but other people use "positively oriented" ones.)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.